# Listing packages in a repositiory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, packages, apt-cache

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 Server. I want to install OpenStack, so I enabled the [Cloud Archive repo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive):

```
sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:havana
```

After the subsequent `update` and `upgrade`, I noticed `python-crypto` changed. `python-crypto` recently fixed a CVE, so I would like to ensure I'm using the patched version of `python-crypto`. I'd also like to compare the `python-crypto` in both Ubuntu and Cloud Archive.

How does one list the package information for both `Ubuntu::python-crypto` and `CloudArchive::python-crypto`?

(And sorry I could not tag this with `apt-cache`. Its not available in the list of tags).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just typing in the name of the new tag works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-cache show packagename
```

works for me, showing the Description, Depends, Provides, Version and so on for all available versions of the package. So does

```
apt-cache showpkg packagename
```

for other information, including the repositories.

```
apt-cache policy packagename
```

is a quick way to get repo and versions.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Is there a way to show it by repo? In my case, two repos are providing the same package, and I want to determine the difference in the packages provided by the two repos.

Comment: Yes. `apt-cache showpkg packagename` includes the repo along with all the other things it shows. If all you want to know is the repos and version, `apt-cache policy packagename` is much more concise.